# IIS7 on Windows 7 and trying to browse to localhost:80 changes to localhost

Tags: iis-7

On Windows 7 I open IE 8 and browse to localhost:80 and something is changing it to localhost.
Why is this happening?

The same happens if i browse to 127.0.0.1:80 it changes to 127.0.0.1 (without the port).

I am trying to use fiddler to browse locally i.e. via http://localhost./80 and it is not working

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost:80 and http://localhost both are equal (and home). So don't worry :-)

(Port 80 is the default http port)

The actual answer to the problem is here: http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: I am getting an very odd Internet Explorer 8 crash when I browse my web site on localhost (hence the reason why I am trying to hook up fiddler to localhost).  IE v8 doesn't crash when I use the pc name or ip address.  Having trouble getting fiddler to see localhost.

Answer (score 0):

IE removes :80.

If you want to troubleshoot the IE 8 crash issue, you may capture a crash dump and analyze it,

http://www.dumpanalysis.org/